# Allowing a dynamic list of IP addresses to access a specific port in an AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: security, amazon-ec2

The problem I am trying to solve today is DDoS. I am working on a game project which is hosted on a TCP port (7777). The game is known to have a community full of idiots (pardon the language) that do not like competition among communities, so they just like to DDoS servers to... kill the competition instead. Depending on the attack, it could cause the game server to crash, or even overload the bandwidth of the entire machine.

My theoretical solution to this problem is creating a dynamic firewall containing the IPs of registered users. Only allowed IPs would be granted the access to the 7777 port. In this way, botnets would be prevented to even reach the server and cause damage. Practically speaking though, I have no idea on how to reach this solution.

I am using Amazon Web Services and their firewalls are Security Groups. The problem is that they have a limit of 50 entries in the IP address inbound list, which is not an acceptable an amount since all users would need to be inside that table.

How can I solve this?

Notes:

- Assume all the other ports, SSH excluded, will be blocked.

(not sure if this is the right site, feel free to move to ServerFault if it'd feel like a better place)

Comment: Without an actual software development question, yes, this is the wrong site.

Comment: You should check the AWS WAF. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl.html

Comment: @DanWilson WAF is only for web requests. My scenario uses 7777 port, TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the tools mentioned in your post, one potential way to solve this is through the use of Lambda function. It might be overkill for your situation but you could have a function determine the required I.P Addresses and then maintain the Security Group based on that, you could add auditing and alerting as required.